How to get Scale Center
I read about Scale Center and the instructions simply set go to Setup and enter "Scale Center" in setup search.  I do not see Scale Center in any orgs.  Not in production; not in a sandbox; not in a dev org.
Does anyone know of what needs to be done to get Scale Center in Seupt?

Do you have an Unlimited Edition of Salesforce? it seems to be only for those as per https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.scale_center_overview.htm&type=5

From the Product page

Scale Center is free to use and is accessible in all UE production and full-copy sandbox orgs.
Product considerations:
Scale Center has no impact on org performance and does not access your org data
Please note that Scale Center isn’t supported in Government Cloud Plus
If you would like Scale Center enabled in a non-UE org, please reach out to your account representative

So - upgrade to Unlimited Edition or contact your rep to see what the price is for Scale Center as an add-on.
I do not see it as an option in our EE Your Account app.
